# Java String length method

Tags: java, string, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Java, for a string x, what is the runtime cost of s.length()? Is it O(1) or O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254726/in-java-for-a-string-x-what-is-the-runtime-cost-of-s-length-is-it-o1-or-o)

How exactly does the length method of String class work in Java ?

Is it a for loop in linear time or there is a field keeping the track of length so that its constant time ?

Comment: Use [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#658) to find out. You'll love it. (BTW that's a link I've posted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of a `String` is kept as a field as seen here : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.length%28%29

Answer (score 1):

There is a field to store the length. It doesn't need to "keep track of it" (with the implication that it might change) because strings are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

String stores its data in `char[]` array but there are cases when String should only use part of that array, that is why in its fields it stores beginning index (`int offset`) of that array, and length that should be used to generate String (`int count`). Method `length()` will return value of `count` field.

Answer (score 0):

A String is Immutable, so when a String object is created a its length is stored as an Instance variable for that String Object.

Comment: That "so" implies more causality than there really is... You could have immutable strings without a length field, and a StringBuffer probably also has a length field, and it is not immutable.

Comment: "so" is used in a context of reasoning here...